# mysql with left join is slow with empty row

Tags: mysql

I have a following query:

```
Select a.field1,a.field2, b.field3, c.field4 from a 
left join b on b. field3=a.field3
left join c on c.field4= b.field4
```

key of b.field3, b.field4, c.field4 and a.field3 has alreay been set.

the speed is extremely slow when b is empty.

Any ideas?

Comment: how about adding index on `b(field3) and c(field4)` if not done already.

Comment: Are the field types for field3 on a and b and field4 on b and c the same? (i.e. both INT or both VARCHAR of same length).

Comment: @virmaior , the field types are the same.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty tried that

Comment: How many records are there in the tables?

Comment: is there also a WHERE condition or is this the entire query? Can you add the output of the EXPLAIN ... of this query?

Answer (score 2):

This is a known MySQL bug:

https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=69721

If you run query with optimizer_switch='block_nested_loop=off', it finishes instantly.

Try this:

```
set optimizer_switch='block_nested_loop=off';
Select a.field1,a.field2, b.field3, c.field4 from a 
left join b on b. field3=a.field3
left join c on c.field4= b.field4;
```